# Can a Muslim girl make accounts on social media?

Tags: sharia, women, hijab, social-media, modernity

We all know that Islam teaches a woman to reveal herself only to her family & other females.
If I make account on Instagram and upload my photos, then is it correct?
Because here I am revealing myself to everybody but only by photos & not physically. So, By doing would it be against Islamic Laws. I mean it wouldn't be something like losing my 'pardah'.

Comment: Part of the religion, in fact, a great percentage of the ISLAM is about Modesty. Modesty is not only limited to your dress code but how you behave, talk, act etc. Basically everything that makes you human includes modesty. When you talk about "reveal herself only to her family & other females", I am assuming you're talking about dressing more freely?

Comment: Secondly, when you ask "If I make an account on Instagram and upload my photos, then is it correct? Because here I am revealing myself to everybody but only by photos & not physically"...and u are saying u're gonna upload photos of yourself...what does that "yourself"/"myself" mean? Are you referring to revealing yourself to the world, while you r displaying your awrah, are you revealing yourself to the world with impolite or immodest speech, are you displaying yourself to the world with immodest attitude? If you doing none of that, I don't see why it would be a point of objection.

Comment: Note, I'm not a scholar. I'm just talking from the perspective of an average Muslim, who happens to research a quite obsessively on Islam.

Answer (score -1):

It is not recommended for a Muslim girl to make a social media account, and also not recommended to upload photos of oneself online as it causes a lot of fitnah and destruction.

You can have WhatsApp with only your family and female friends, without your photo on profile pics.

MAY ALLAH GUIDE YOU THE RIGHT PATHS.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. This may be more useful if you could provide evidences to support your claims. See [answer]

Comment: @Syed ghouse Please provide evidence as to why is social media "haram" for a Muslim woman. Secondly, if the picture of a woman leads to fitnah, then I'd say revealing her face in the public would cause finish as well. Well, in that case, it's haram to go outside of the house....is that what u're implying? Please help me understand, brother.

Answer (score -1):

Islam teaches both men and women to be modest. What modesty means is interpreted variously by various cultures. Islam also teaches men and women to be at home in the world. As social media is part of the world, it is not against the use of social media. It is what one actually writes or does that matters.